# Vim type after cursor or how to open parenthesis fast?

Tags: vim

I recently watched [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7U12a-TTtfo&t=304s) where the presenter was typing out a program and very quickly entered curly braces and moved the closing brace to a new line.
And then they entered text to the right of the cursor without moving it.
How to do this?

Comment: SO deals with programming problems, not reverse-engineering youtube videos. I voted to close. Why not just ask the presenter of that video?

Comment: Presenter is not answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be plugins for this kind of auto-closing brackets trick.
However, without installing plugins, you can achieve it with two mappings.

First, you need a auto close `{...}` mapping:

```
:inoremap { {}<left>
```

Then, if you want "enter" to move the closing `}` to the next line, you can add a  insert mode mapping:

```
:inoremap <expr> <cr> ( '}' == strcharpart(getline('.')[col('.')-1 :], 0, 1)) ? "\<cr>\<esc>%o" : "\<CR>"
```

Of course, **these two mappings merely show an idea of how to achieve your goal. You may want to polish it to make it fit your needs.**

With these two mappings, it works like this (vim9.1):
[image: text]

Comment: Thanks a lot for an answer! And, if You know, please tell, how to solve second problem. How to type to the right of the cursor?

Comment: @KoD you're welcome. I don't get your question. "type to the right of the cursor"?  what did you mean exactly? have you tried the two mappings?